# Displaying values of an object.name in a sheetJS excel sheet

Tags: angular, sheetjs

I am creating a sheetJS xlsx sheet in my Angular app from an array of models. Each model structure is as below,

```
{
 id: number,
 category: {
   id: number,
   name: string,
 },
 name: string
}
```

I want the sheet to show the data as follows,

```
 id     |   name      | category
  1        Coke          Drink
  2        Chocolate     Food
```

Currently the category column is blank,

My code for creating the workbook is,

```
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(filteredModels);
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Ingredients');
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'Ingredients.xlsx', { compression: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use `map` something like this: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(
  filteredModels.map((item) => {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name,
      category: item.category.name,
    };
  })
);
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhomu3?file=src%2Fmain.ts)